# Adding random samples from one spark dataframe to another

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes like this:

```
| User |
 ------
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
```

and

```
| Articles |
 ----------
| 'A'      |
| 'B'      |
| 'C'      |
```

What's an intuitive way to assign each user 2 `articles` randomly?
The output dataframe might look like this:

```
| User | Articles |
 -----------------
| 1    | 'A'      |
| 1    | 'C'      |
| 2    | 'C'      |
| 2    | 'B'      |
| 3    | 'C'      |
| 3    | 'A'      |
```

Here's the code that will generate these two dataframes:

```
u =[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(u)
users = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(user_id=x[0]))
users_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(users)

a = [('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',), ('E',)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(a)
articles = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(article_id=x[0]))
articles_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(articles)
```

Comment: Is the articles data frame large?

Comment: It's small - in the hundreds rows. Users is around ~200k rows

Answer (score 0):

Since your article list is small it makes sense to keep it as a python object and not as a distributed list. This will allow you to create a udf to produce a random list of articles for each user_id. The following is one way you could do so:

```
from random import sample,seed
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,explode
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType,StringType

class ArticleRandomizer(object):
    def __init__(self,article_list,num_articles=2,preseed=0):
        self.article_list=article_list
        self.num_articles=num_articles
        self.preseed=preseed
    def getrandom(self,user):
        seed(user+self.preseed)
        return sample(self.article_list,self.num_articles)

u =[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(u)
users = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(user_id=x[0]))
users_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(users)

a = [('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',), ('E',)]
#rdd = sc.parallelize(a)
#articles = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(article_id=x[0]))
#articles_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(articles)

article_list=[article[0] for article in a]
ARandomizer=ArticleRandomizer(article_list)
add_articles=udf(ARandomizer.getrandom,ArrayType(StringType()))
users_df.select('user_id',explode(add_articles('user_id'))).show()
```

This `ArticleRandomizer.getrandom` function is seeded by the `user_id`, so it is deterministic, meaning you will get the same random list of articles for a given user for each run. You can adjust this to get a potentially different list by changing the `preseed` value when you instantiate the class.

This hasn't been tested to see if it will scale well, but it should work fine on your dataset because the dimension of the articles and the users are both fairly small.

Answer (score 0):

If indeed the Articles DataFrame is pretty small we can run `collect_list` which will take the entire DataFrame and make it one row with an Array column.

```
|      Articles   |
 -----------------
| ['A', 'B', 'C'] |
```

Then we can cross-join this table to the Users one, randomly generate two different integers (this is the main part of the code below) and then just pick the two elements from the Articles column .

`explode` function is used in order to achieve the format you presented in the original question.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, rand, when, col, size, floor, explode, array

articles_collected = articles.agg(collect_list("Articles").alias("articles"))

users \
.join(articles_collected, how="cross") \
.withColumn(
  "first_rand",
  floor(rand() * size("articles"))
) \
.withColumn(
  "second_rand",
  when(
    col("first_rand") == 0,
    floor(rand() * (size("articles") - 1)) + 1
  ).otherwise(
    floor(rand() * col("first_rand"))
  )
) \
.withColumn(
  "articles_picked",
  array(
    col("articles").getItem(col("first_rand").cast("int")),
    col("articles").getItem(col("second_rand").cast("int"))
  )
) \
.select(
  "User",
  explode("articles_picked").alias("Articles")
)
```